# Set ARITHABORT and ANSI_WARINGS ON with using TRY - CATCH

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to test result when ARITHABORT and ANSI_WARINGS are ON in Compatibility level 80 and Compatibility level 140. I use TRY - CATCH to catch domain errors too.
The result is different in two level.
In compatibility level 80, error conditions cause the query to end and CATCH clause is not executed.
In compatibility level 140, error conditions cause the query to end and CATCH clause is executed.

Can you explain why have different in two compatibility level?

This is my code:

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT SQRT(-1)
    PRINT N'OSQL Success'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'OSQL Failure'
END CATCH
```

Comment: 80 is SQL Server 2000. There was no TRY/CATCH back then. In fact, I'm surprised you don't get a syntax error immediatelly

Comment: What's the point of using compatibility level 80? SQL Server 2000 is *very* old and many of the features used nowadays didn't exist back then. The database engine is *completely* different which means that setting the compatibility level to 80 won't make a database work as if it was a SQL Server 2000 instance

Comment: I think SQL Server 2008 was the last one to even offer compatibility level 80, and even *it* is out of support now.

Comment: The fact that you are using Compatibility 80 and 140 (2000 and 2017) means you're using 2 different instances as well. The *newest* version of SQL Server that supported level 80 was SQL Server 2008(R2); which are also completely out of support. Considering that the compatibility and version of SQL server you are using differ so greatly, I'm surprised you do expect the same behaviour.

Comment: It was, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. 2012 only supports 90-110.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis Kanavos, I upgrade compatibility level 80 to compatibility level 140. I don't know why in level 80, the errors is not catch by the CATCH clause.

Comment: What instance were you on to "upgrade" the level to 140, @NganMai? The only environments to support 140 are SQL Server 2017 (and 2019 preview) and Azure. All 3 of those, however, only support level 100+ ([ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)). It would have been impossible for you to "upgrade" the level without changing the instance you are using or upgrading the instance itself (which you would have to upgrade from 2000 to 2008 and then to 2017).

Comment: Hi Larnu, I upgrade from 2000 to 2008 and then to 2017

Comment: At level 80, you're likely getting a *compilation error*. Your `CATCH` clause can't save you because the code doesn't even compile, let alone run or enter the `TRY` block.

Comment: @NganMai, what error do you get with 80? Are you using OSQL as the print messages suggest?